# Writing polynomial conjunctions with MAGMA calculation software

Tags: polynomials

Magma Computational was created by the University of Sydney, and recently I've been learning to use Magma to calculate knotted equations, but I'm a rookie and the answers I get are always incorrect, so I'd like to ask for your help.
Here,computing the resultant of two polynomials with respect to y by MAGMA.
The first one is $x^2 y^3 + x y^3 + x^3 y^2 + x^3 y + x^3 + y^6 + y^5 + y^4$ and
the second one is $x^6 y^2 + x^6 y + x^4 y^3 + x^2 y^3 + y^3 + x^{12} + x^{10} + x^8$, where $x$ belongs to $F_2^n/F_2$ and two polynomials are belong to $F_2[x]$.